# TextView is invisible in Custom Dialog when runing in simulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am facing to some weired problem where the "textview" of my custom dialog get displayed in Eclipse Layout editor but not when it is running in simulator/phone.

Following is my Custom dialog box layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="350dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_this_app_image_4" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/rate_this_app_text"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
         android:text="@string/rate_this_app_text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rate_this_app_yes_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rate_this_app_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/rate_this_app_yes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rate_this_app_not_now_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rate_this_app_text"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/rate_this_app_yes_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/rate_this_app_notNow" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/rate_this_app_dont_ask_button"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/rate_this_app_not_now_button"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rate_this_app_not_now_button"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate_this_app_not_now_button"
         android:text="@string/rate_this_app_dontAsk" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the Java code, which calls the dialog

```
private void showRatingDialog()
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rate_this_app);
        dialog.setTitle("Classifique este aplicativo");

        //Register the Buttons
        Button yesButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.rate_this_app_yes_button);
        Button notNowButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.rate_this_app_not_now_button);
        Button dontAskButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.rate_this_app_dont_ask_button);

        TextView textView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.rate_this_app_text);
        textView.setText("Gostaria de classificar este aplicativo agora?");

        //Register the listener for 'Yes' button
        yesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }});


        //Register the listener for 'Not Now' button
        notNowButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }});


        //Register the listener for 'Do not ask' button
        dontAskButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }});

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Now, following is how it get displayed in Eclipse Layout editor

[image]

Now, following is how it get displayed in Simulator/phone

[image]

As you can see, the TextView is disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default text color is white with Holo theme. And you do not see it over the White BG. Set the text color in your XML.